# Easiest way to render an Integer without thousands separator when using Fields plugin 2.0.2

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, gsp, grails-domain-class

I'm building a very basic app using **Grails 3.0.2**.

I have a domain class called **Unit** which contains, among others, a field called **season**, whose type is Integer and represents a year.

I have used the command **generate-views** to generate the scaffolded views.

Once running the application, when an existing instance is shown, the season is displayed using "," as thousands separator, and I want to remove it.

What is the easiest way to override (only) the format of the season?

For testing purposes, I have modified the **show.gsp** of the Unit class in the following manner:

```
<f:with bean="unit">
    <f:display />
    <f:display property="season" />
</f:with>
```

The `<f:display property="season" />` displays simply "1,975", but ignores the label.

I've tried to understand the documentation of the [Fields plugin](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/single.html#customizingFieldRendering), but I do not achieve what I want so it's obvious that I do not understand it.

I have added `_displayWidget.gsp` under `views/_fields/unit/season` (I have also tried under `views/unit/season`), but the outcome is exactly the same than before, so I assume the plugin is not taking them into account.

```
<g:formatNumber groupingUsed="false" number="${value}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `_displayWidget.gsp` convention, but a simpler approach might be to override the display of the unit.season property by adding a `_display.gsp` under `views/_fields/unit/season` containing just the following:

```
${value}
```

Comment: The [fields-plugin documentation](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html) says that since version 1.5 the `_display.gsp` has been replaced by `_displayWrapper.gsp`, and a new `_displayWidget.gsp` has been introduced fulfilling the same purpose but displaying the widget without the wrapper.

Comment: Documentation for the Grails 3 version of the fields plugin (2.0.x) is a bit difficult to find, but I located a link to it on the plugin's [github page](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields) near the bottom.  That will take you [here](http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/).  It only mentions the `_display.gsp` option and doesn't mention the replacement you found in the 1.5 documentation.  Not sure what that means long term, but I did a quick test and confirmed the approach that I mentioned worked.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Good that you found the 2.0.x documentation, though It's a little bit contradictory. I have tested `_display.gsp` in my application and it still does not work. I will give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.  [Here](https://github.com/scrain/Grails-3-Fields-Plugin-Integer-Question) is my working test app in case it provides any additional insight.

Comment: I've run your test-app and it works. Same grails and fields-plugin versions that I'm using and same views, templates etc, and works. There's something wrong in my app and I can't figure out what it is, but your answer is 100% right.

Comment: FYI this was ultimately due to the timing on when the Grails 3 version of the plugin was forked and ported.  I reported [the issue](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/issues/13) and it was resolved.  You might be able to give your original approach another try now with new [2.1.0-SNAPSHOT](http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/) version.

Answer (score 0):

Diego, you can format any given number using the taglib formatNumber:

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html

Use the param 'format' and check the DecimalFormat patterns to find the one that suits fine for you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Iván that's clear, look at the last few lines of my example.

The question is how to override the **fields-plugin** template in order to make the `<f:display bean="${unit}" property="season" />` be transformed into the content of the new template.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in Grails 3.1.14 by creating views/_fields/myDomainClass/myFieldName/_displayWrapper.gsp and containing a single line of ${value}